# Is there a way to Wait asynchronously on multiple SemaphoreSlim like WaitHandle.WaitAny()

Tags: c#

I am converting an application to async and it uses Semaphores in a few places.

Converting these Semaphores to SemaphoreSlims, I am able to asynchronously wait using WaitAsync in most places.

However, in a few places, the application waits on multiple Semaphores using WaitHandle.WaitAny()

Is there an efficient way to achieve this functionality in an asynchronous way?

Basically, how can I convert the following general code asynchronous:

```
Semaphore sem1 = new Semaphore(1,1);
SemaPhore sem2 = new Semaphore(1,1);

WaitHandle[] sems = new WaitHande[2];
sems[0] = sem1;
sems[1] = sem2;

int index = WaitHandle.WaitAny(sems);

if(index = 0){ do some operation }
else if(index == 1) { do some other operation }
```

I want to avoid using Task.Run and the same blocking call because that will strain the threadpool as threads would be blocked while waiting, something like:

```
await Task.Run(() => WaitHandle.WaitAny(sems));
```

Also, I am not limited to using SemaphoreSlim, and would consider any similar construct.
But, I do need the throttling that Semaphores provide.

Comment: Can't you use `Task.WhenAll()` or `Task.WhenAny()`?

Comment: Can you use `SemaphoreSlim` instead?

Comment: Can you add a lock around code so only one thread can access code at one time.  Then you do not need SLIM.  Slim limits the number of threads that can access a resource or pool of resources concurrently

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.registerwaitforsingleobject?view=net-6.0

Comment: @klekmek Thanks! Yes, Task.WhenAny can be used, only issue was taking care of not acquiring BOTH the SemaphoreSlims. Stephen's answer takes care of that issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use `SemaphoreSlim`, then the answer can use `WhenAny`; you just need to be sure to cancel or release the semaphore you *don't* want:

```
SemaphoreSlim sem1 = new(1,1);
SemaphoreSlim sem2 = new(1,1);
CancellationTokenSource cts = new();
Action done;

var sem1Task = sem1.WaitAsync(cts.Token);
var sem2Task = sem2.WaitAsync(cts.Token);

var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(sem1Task, sem2Task);
cts.Cancel();
if (completedTask == sem1Task)
{
  done = sem1.Release;
  await ReleaseIfNecessaryAsync(sem2Task, sem2);
}
else
{
  done = sem2.Release;
  await ReleaseIfNecessaryAsync(sem1Task, sem1);
}

if (completedTask == sem1Task) { do some operation }
else if (completedTask == sem2Task) { do some other operation }

done();

static async Task ReleaseIfNecessaryAsync(Task waitTask, SemaphoreSlim sem)
{
  try
  {
    await waitTask;
    sem.Release();
  }
  catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
}
```

Comment: thanks Stephen for the answer. I was concerned about the other SemaphoreSlim being acquired if I used WaitAsync, and your answer has provided a good way to deal with that contingency.